# First integral of ODE system

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to make sense out of the first integral of non-linear ODE systems.

$\bullet$ Is the first integral only relevant to a certain type of ODE's e.g. autonomous, first order?

$\bullet$ How is the first integral generally defined and/or calculated of say:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot x\\\dot y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x-y\\ xy
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$\bullet$ What can I normally do knowing it (very generally speaking)?

Thanks for your help.

Edit: Concrete problem is given (Open to suggestions)

Comment: Well that's the thing @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, I have not used the first integrals and that's why I'm asking. There is no explanation in the books from university and the one the professor gave us is just applied to a single ODE.

Comment: Sometimes there are no solution for the second point. It depends on the functions. You should choose some examples of $f_1,f_2$ because it's too general to get an answer. There is no general formula for even first order non linear differential equation. +1 for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first integral is any function that is constant along the solutions of the ODE. Conversely, given a set of first integrals and their values at an initial point, the solution of the ODE has to lie completely in the intersection of the corresponding level hypersurfaces.

In general there is no guarantee that such a thing exists.

There are certain situations where a first integral automatically exists, such in Hamiltonian systems where the energy function is a first integral. The Noether theorem tells that any (Lie-) symmetry provides another first integral, such as momentum and angular momentum for translational and rotational invariance of the equations.

In some other exceptional examples like the minimal Lotka-Volterra system, a first integral can be found and shows that the solutions are periodic on concentric orbits.

In the given example, if you can find an integrating factor for 
$$
xy\,dx+(y-x)dy=0,
$$
then the integral of that would be a first integral.

Comment: How exactly did you come up with the formula?

Comment: If $F(x,y)=C$ on a solution curve, then in the time derivative $F_x\dot x+F_y\dot y=0$, which means $F_x=\mu\dot x$ and $F_y=-\mu\dot y$ for some integrating factor $\mu$.